# TextBox not listening Enter key before Space key is pressed in C#

Tags: c#

I have to process an "Enter" key event on text box so I created a new class inheriting from textBox and have already overridden the IsInputKey method. Problem is the KeyDown event is not being fired with out pressing the space bar first.

```
public class EnterTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

After creating from the above class as

```
EnterLisTextBox enterTextBox1 = new EnterLisTextBox();            
enterTextBox1.KeyDown += enterTextBox1_KeyDown;
```

the key down event handler is

```
void enterTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed enter");;
    }  
}
```

But this only works if I pressed the "Space bar" before using the "Enter key". But once i pressed the space bar even if I retype every thing on the text box it works. Why is this? Why is it the prerequisite to press the space bar?

**UPDATE:**

Implementing keyPress event worked for me, but if any one has any idea why the above not worked before using the sapce bar. This is the how i used keypress, note the ***e.KeyChar == '\r'***

```
void enterTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed enter");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Does the TextBox have focus?

Comment: I tested and it works as expected. Maybe there is something else in your project that affects the behavior of `EnterTextBox`...

Comment: Not for me, but the keyPress is working like expected. I've not done any thing with EnterTextBox that I've not posted above.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the enter key does not count as "normal" key in this event, so you have to explicitly make it an input key in the PreviewKeyDown event method:

```
    private void enterTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
                e.IsInputKey = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                e.IsInputKey = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Enter:
                e.IsInputKey = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is also true for the arrow keys, for example. And of course, your textbox needs to have the focus first.

Answer (score 0):

> First you have to select TextBox and then you have to press enter key ,otherwise
>   KeyDown Event on Textbox won't be fired.
>
> Coming to your case when you press Spacebar your textbox is getting
>   the focus/being selected hence there after your textbox is able to handle enter
>   key event.

Comment: that is not the problem, the problem is after typing it won't accept the enter key. I have to press the space bar then delete it if i don't need a space. Then it fires the event.

Comment: Just solved it, implemented the keyPress event and it workd. But why it didn't work for the keyDown is still a mystery to me

Comment: @user2960189: Okay great, but as you are saying we have to identify why it's not working in KeyDown Event